# How do I manage receiving multiple buffers from multiple clients using epoll?

Tags: c, sockets, epoll, recv, multiplexing

I have a server that is using epoll. My question is what is the best way to process all the buffers so I can deal with half messages, or multiple messages coming in a buffer.

**For example:**

If the message is "Hello From Client Number #".

Buffer's received through epoll:

From Client 1: "Hello From"

From Client 2: "Hello From Client Number 2Hello From Client Number 2"

From Client 1: " Client Number 1HelloFromClient Number 1"

In this scenario, I need to be able to identify that "Hello From" is only half a message and store it somewhere. Then I need to be able to process that two whole messages have gone through from Client 2. And then go back and pick up where I left off from Client 1. I know there are ways of distinguishing messages using delimiters, or sending message length, but I'm not quit sure on how to deal with receiving half a message at all.

Does anyone have any ideas, or any sample code I could look at.

*Note* 
I know it's bad that I'm currently processing everything into one buffer. I'm going to change that. Would I need a separate buffer for each client?

Thanks for any help!

```
void epoll(int listening_port)
{
    char buffer[500];       //buffer for message
    int listen_sock = 0;    //file descriptor (fd) for listening socket
    int conn_sock = 0;      //fd for connecting socket
    int epollfd = 0;         // fd for epoll
    int nfds = 0;           //number of fd's ready for i/o
    int i = 0;              //index to which file descriptor we are lookng at
    int curr_fd = 0;        //fd for socket we are currently looking at
    bool loop = 1;          //boolean value to help identify whether to keep in loop or not
    socklen_t address_len;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    struct epoll_event ev, events[EPOLL_MAX_EVENTS];
    ssize_t result = 0;


    bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    bzero(&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = listening_port;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    listen_sock = create_socket();


    if(bind(listen_sock, SA &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) != 0)
    {
        perror("Bind failed");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Bind successful\n");
    }


    set_socket_nonblocking(listen_sock);

    listen_on_socket(listen_sock, SOMAXCONN); //specifying max connections in backlog

    epollfd = initialize_epoll();

    ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT | EPOLLET | EPOLLRDHUP;
    ev.data.fd = listen_sock;

    if(epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, listen_sock, &ev) == ERROR)
    {
        perror("Epoll_ctl: listen sock");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Successfully added listen socket to epoll\n");
    }

    while (RUN_EPOLL)
    {
        nfds = epoll_wait(epollfd, events, EPOLL_MAX_EVENTS, 0); //waiting for incoming connection;
        if(nfds == ERROR)
        {
            perror("EPOLL_Wait");
        }
        //printf("Finished waiting\i");

        for(i = 0; i < nfds; ++i)
        {
            curr_fd = events[i].data.fd;
            loop = true; //reset looping flag
            //Notification from Listening Socket - Process Incoming Connections

            if (curr_fd == listen_sock) {

                while(loop)
                {
                    conn_sock = accept(listen_sock, SA &serv_addr, &address_len); //accept incoming connection
                    printf("Accepted new incoming connection - socket fd: %d\n", conn_sock);
                    if (conn_sock > 0) //if successful set socket nonblocking and add it to epoll
                    {

                        set_socket_nonblocking(conn_sock);

                        ev.events = EPOLLIN | EPOLLOUT| EPOLLET | EPOLLRDHUP; //setting flags
                        ev.data.fd = conn_sock; //specify fd of new connection in event to follow
                        if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, conn_sock, &ev) == ERROR) //add fd to monitored fd's
                        {
                            perror("epoll_ctl: conn_sck");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            printf("Added %d to monitor list\n", conn_sock);
                        }


                    }
                    else if (conn_sock == ERROR)
                    {
                        if ((errno == EAGAIN) || (errno == EWOULDBLOCK))
                        {
                            printf("All incoming connections processed\n");
                            loop = false;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            perror("Accept remote socket");
                            loop = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(events[i].events & EPOLLRDHUP) //detecting if peer shutdown
            {
                printf("Detected socket peer shutdown. Closing now. \n");

                if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, curr_fd, NULL) == ERROR) {
                    perror("epoll_ctl: conn_sck");
                }

                close_socket(curr_fd);
            }
            else if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)
            {
                while(loop)
                {
                    result = recv(curr_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                    //printf("Length of incoming message is %d\i", result);

                    if(result > 0) //
                    {
                        printf("File Descriptor: %d. Message: %s\n", curr_fd, buffer); //I know this will need to be changd
                        bzero(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
                    }
                    else if(result == ERROR) //Message is completely sent
                    {

                        if(errno == EAGAIN)
                        {

                            loop = false;

                        }
                    }
                    else if(result == 0)
                    {
                        //Removing the fd from the monitored descriptors in epoll
                        if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, curr_fd, NULL) == ERROR) {
                            perror("epoll_ctl: conn_sck");
                        }
                        close_socket(curr_fd); //Closing the fd
                        loop = false;
                    }

                }

            }
        }

    }

    close_socket(listen_sock);
    //need to develop way to gracefully close out of epoll

    return;

}
```

Comment: `recv(curr_fd, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);` and `printf("File Descriptor: %d. Message: %s\n", curr_fd, buffer);` will result in undefined behavior if `sizeof(buffer)` bytes are received as there is no space for a `'\0'` terminator.

Answer (score 1):

> Would I need a separate buffer for each client?

Yes. You will need to store a separate client state for each client. As part of that client's state, the partial message buffer should also be stored separately for each client.

> Does anyone have any ideas, or any sample code I could look at.

You could look at the code for [the facil.io library](http://facil.io), and it's [raw-HTTP example code](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/fe7574d70c0bd3aa73a8d592cb902cfd6b8b8837/examples/raw-http.c).

In the example code you will notice that [each HTTP client (protocol / state object)](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/fe7574d70c0bd3aa73a8d592cb902cfd6b8b8837/examples/raw-http.c#L55-L71) will have it's own target [buffer for reading](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/fe7574d70c0bd3aa73a8d592cb902cfd6b8b8837/examples/raw-http.c#L236-L251).

The facil.io library uses `epoll` under the hood (or `kqueue` on BSD/macOS and `poll` if you really want to go portable) - so the framework's logic applies to your case.

Sometimes it's possible to use a stack allocated (or per-thread) buffer, but this is only true if you later copy the data you need to keep.